# Склонение названий

Tags: склонение, ономастика

Склоняются ли названия, такие как "аэропорт "Пулково", "гостиница "Метрополь" и т.д. И если да, то как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если название употребляется сместе с определением, как, например, "кинотеатр "Космос", "кафе "Ромашка", то названия не склоняются, а изменяется только определяемое слово.
Пример: *пойти в кафе "Ромашка", жить рядом с кинотеатром "Космос"*.
Если же определяемого слова нет, то название склоняется.
Пример: *пойти в "Ромашку", жить рядом с "Космосом"*.